# show that $d'(x,y) = |e^x - e^y|$ induces the same topology as the standard metric in R

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

to prove that  I thought about doing this in two parts 
first, prove that we can find an open Ball $B'_r(x)$ with $B'_r(x) := \{y \in \mathbb{R} . |e^x - e^y| < r\} $ which is a contained in the ball $B_r(x)$ with $B_r(x) := \{y \in \mathbb{R} . |x-y| < r\} $ 
so let $ y \in B'_r(x)\implies |e^x-e^y| < r$. the problem is how do I get from there to the fact that $|x-y| < r$ ? 
and for the second part which is proving that the ball of the standard metric can be contained in a ball with $d'$ I think I have the same problem. can anybody help with that please? Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use the same $r$ both times, so it should be $B'_{r'}$  Then you can just take $r'$ small enough in the first case and $r$ small enough in the second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I do that then there is nothing to prove. We can always find a smaller radius

Comment: You still have to argue that if I give you a $B_r(x)$ you can find a small enough $r'$ to get $B'_{r'}(x)$ inside it. The fact that the metric is a continuous function of $y$ is enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that $y_n\rightarrow y$ in the metic $d'$ iff $y_n\rightarrow y$ in the standard metric.

This follows by continuity of the exponential function and its inverse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do this implies that both metrics induce the same topology?

Comment: They would produce the  same closed sets. If a point is a accumulation point of a set $A$ with respect  one metric, it will be also an accumulation point with respect the the other metric.